# log4j, maven jar plugin, and properties file

Tags: jar, maven, log4j

I'm creating a jar with the maven-jar-plugin. I can't for the life of me get this jar to read a log4j properties file which is in the same directory as my jar file. My steps are:

1. mvn package
2. copy log4j.properties to target dir
3. java -Dlog4j.configuration = log4j.properties -cp . -jar Myjar

I've tried multiple variations of this. It seems like this should be an easy thing to do.

FWIW here's the relevant part of my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>loadtester.TestClient</mainClass>
                        <packageName>loadtester</packageName>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `java -jar`, `-cp` entries are [ignored](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t142693-java-jar-ignore-the-classpath-command-line-argument.html). Thus log4j.properties is not read.

As @Dave has mentioned, you can include `log4j.properties` in the jar.  Alternately, you can try the following

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file://full/path//of/log4j.properties -jar Myjar
```

Comment: The reason I don't have it baked into the jar is that I'd like to modify it after I've packaged things up.

Answer (score 1):

try copying it to target/classes

Is there any reason you don't have that in your source under src/main/resources/log4j.properties?